# Can Cypher trapwires be destroyed from either side?

Tags: valorant

When placing trapwires with Cypher in Valorant does it matter which side you place on?

Consider a hallway, and placing the trapwire across it.  If placed on the left side of the wall, the trap will span the hallway.  When an opponent triggers the trap, they have a chance to destroy the trap wire device on the wall.  Must they destroy the same location placed (left), or are there two locations they could destroy (left or right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place a trapwire, the enemy can destroy it from both sides, no matter which side you place it on the wall